# Read in a dataframe from .txt file with special characters in R

Tags: r, special-characters

I have speech transcriptions with lots of special characters in a column in a dataframe, like so:

```
">like I don't understand< sorry like how old's your mom¿"
"°ye[a:h]°"
"°I don't know°"
```

When I read-in the dataframe using `read.table`, I get the following output where several funny new characters have incorrecly been inserted:

Output in R:

```
">like I don't understand< sorry like how old's your momÂ¿"
"Â°ye[a:h]Â°"
"Â°I don't knowÂ°"
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: This is almost certainly an "encoding" issue. Try `read.table(..., encoding="latin1")`; if that doesn't work, there are many questions on SO about encoding problems, many of them are OS-specific, so look for one that matches your current environment. (It may help if you included the output from `sessionInfo()` in your question. Thanks!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the enconding while importing or just it after importing the data.

#### Option 1

```
df <- read.table('path/file.ext', econding = "UTF-8", ...)
```

#### Option 2

```
x <- c(
  ">like I don't understand< sorry like how old's your momÂ¿",
  "Â°ye[a:h]Â°",
  "Â°I don't knowÂ°")

Encoding(x) <- 'UTF-8'

print(x)
```